# Year on Year growth percentages vs share price returns

Tags: time-series, granger-causality

Say I have 2 time series A and B.
A is a time series of year-on-year growth numbers at quarterly intervals (I don't have the index levels). For example a data point as at 30-Sep-20 of +17.7% represents the year on year growth from 30-Sep-19.

B is a time series of total returns of a stock at quarterly intervals. A data point as at 30-Sep-20 of +10% represents the total return 3 months to 30-Sep-20.

If I wanted to test whether A is a leading indicator of B using a granger causality test or test if there is a relationship between the 2 time series, what would be the best way to make both series comparable?

Does it make sense to turn the time series of year-on-year growth numbers into an index starting from 100? Can think of it as a seasonally adjusted index.

Or should the share price returns also be converted into year-on-year numbers. Ie do time series analysis by converting B into a time series of year-on-year stock returns.

Please see the example below which to visualize it:

| Date | A | B | Indexed A | Indexed B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/03/2020 |  |  | 100 | 100 |
| 30/06/2020 | 15 | 5 | 115 | 105 |
| 30/09/2020 | 17.7 | 10 | 132 | 115.5 |

Comment: *"B is a time series of total returns of a stock at quarterly intervals. A data point as at 30-Sep-20 of +10% represents the total return 3 months to 30-Sep-20.* - did you mean 30-Jun-20 here?

Comment: No the 10% represents the total return from 30-Jun-20 to 30-Sep-20

Answer (score 1):

First, note that converting to index doesn't change the inherent information of the series so wouldn't make any difference. In fact, you are just making the series non-stationary, which then again will have to be differenced (or log differenced) for analysis.

Second, whether the series are comparable, is not the right question, I think. You can just think of them as two series that can be compared the way you like.

The problem here is that if for the series A, call it $x_t$, you had QoQ rates, it would have contained more information and would have been better (an interesting thing is that suppose the QoQ rate was available as another series C, it would be a leading indicator of A). Unfortunately, the QoQ information is lost.

Third, converting B to YoY (say the new series is now D) is again losing some information. Yes it might appear now that A is a leading indicator of D, but information gain from A now may be less than the information lost in the process of converting B to D.

Finally, it would be better to just use the current data as it is (though you should appropriately seasonally adjust the series B). This is perhaps the most efficient way of using the available information.

Comment: Thanks I understand that converting to index doesn't change inherent information of the series but does it makes sense to convert a time series of YoY changes like that? Normally with an index you would not want the % changes to overlap.

Comment: @user3381431: whether creating an index makes sense of not depends on what you are making index of. In your question, you seem to be trying to regenerate the underlying index - which is not possible unless you have data for index level for $x_{-4}$ to $x_{-1}$. On the other hand, if you are creating the index of inflation series itself, then you'll have to define a base. Say you assume that inflation in period 1, is 100. Then the rate of change of index changes completely. It now tells you by what percent has the inflation rate changed. That's more like acceleration rate of underlying series.

Comment: Ok with the stock return series I can create a series of YoY returns. Should it be transformed like so if I want to use both in time series analysis, given that the first series can only be YoY numbers?

Comment: @user3381431: I don’t think it’s necessary to transform your series B to YoY. The frequency of both series is quarterly and can very well be used. It’s just that in QoQ form series B has more noise but then it also has more info.